# Android - Google SignInButton text is not centered

Tags: android, google-signin

I'd like to use a `com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton` in one of my layouts but sadly, and without any valuable reason, the text inside the button doesn't want to be in the center.

Here is how it look :

[image]

The xml is really simple and I tried to play with the margin/padding/gravity/... but nothing works to center the text:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/button_google_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT :

Even with a totally empty activity, this button doesn't display correctly ... Am I crazy?

[image]

Has somebody already encounter this problem?

Thank you

Comment: What is the version of your google play services?

Comment: post the `toolbar` layout please. I have used the Google SignIn Button and it works perfectly for me. So wanted to check if `toolbar` layout is messing up something

Comment: @A.Badakhshan 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'

Comment: @Dibzmania Good idea. I tried without toolbar but that doesn't change anything :/

Comment: @Valentin have you done anything else related to your button in your class seems to be okay and normal  for me with the given details

Comment: @Valentin is the `RelativeLayout` that holds the signin button the root view of some activity or fragment or is it included from within some other layout. For verifying, i just used your code (Used Appwidget Toolbar instead of whatever toolbar layout you used) and there is no issue absolutely.  Another thing, can you enable `Show Layout Bounds` from within `Developer options` and paste the image again

Comment: @Charuක No I don't do anything special. I even tried in a empty activity (only the parent layout and this button) and the result is still the same. I really feel that it's a bug (in the google play services library?) but I would not be the only one with this issue if it was the case ...
By the way, the text is already not centered in the XML Preview.

Comment: @Valentin you are not crazy if thats the case you cannot help it at all go for a custom sign in button and add background as an image

Comment: Are you seeing this in real devices too???

Comment: @A.Badakhshan Yes. In the XML preview, the emulator and real device

Comment: Do me a favor and change your google play services version and install your app on a real device.

Comment: It's working correctly on my side. I have revisited every detail you mentioned and it just works!

Comment: @Valentin whats the google play services version that you installed in your sdk tools ? go to your extras section and see you have any pending updates related to g play services

Comment: read https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/custom-button

Comment: how about setting android:gravity="center" for the Sign In Button?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/button_google_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late answer but for future views..

```
SignInButton signInButton = ((SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in));
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
     View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);
 if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setPadding(0, 8, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />


Use android:layout_gravity="center"
```